# Symfony2 dependencies in class

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

I try to create a class to manage some part of my app
but I need to access the configuration in resources/config.yml

I tryed to extends my class with containerAware as a controler
But he container is not set...

I would like to be able to do something like that:

```
class MyClass extends ContainerAware
{
   public function myFunciton()
   {
      $em = $this->get('Doctrine')->getEntityManager();
   }
}
```

any suggestion is welcome

Comment: My suggestion is to study carefully the section on Services in the reference manual. [Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) Once you have walked through the process then it becomes trivial to inject the entity manager into MyClass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending `ContainerAware` does not automatically grant access to the service container - you would need to inject the container into your class. There are two ways to do that:

- If your class is registered as a service, you can inject `@service_container`
- If your class is not a service, but is being accessed from a class that does have access to the container (like a controller), you can explicitly call `setContainer()`

That being said, **you should not inject the container into your classes**. This makes it harder to test your classes. There are a few exceptions to this, but they don't come up often.

Instead, you should only inject services you need. In the case of the entity manager, you would inject `@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager`.

In regards to accessing data from a config.yml, I would suggest including the file (which can be done when defining a service) and parsing the yml using either `Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser` or `Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml`. The parsers converts a yml string to a PHP variable that you can then easily work with.

Comment: Does this work for the entity?
Like to be able to self save the entity?
ex: $entity->save()

Comment: No. Entities are plain PHP objects. They have no knowledge of the entity manager, nor should they. You're thinking of the Active Record pattern from Doctrine 1. Doctrine 2 uses the Data Mapper pattern.